# Save a checkbox state ( remember me) in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I would Like to save my checkbox always checked after the first checking, when the user presses it , the thing works but when i exit the app the check box is reseted , is there a way to prevent this? Now I have to check it again every time I move out the page login:

I want also to Log in only one time sow I dont have to repeat it each time I go out the application or when I come back to the login page

**LoginActivity.java**

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText mEmail,mPassword;
TextView mCreateBtn,forgotTextLink;
Button mLoginBtn;
ProgressBar progressBar;
FirebaseAuth fAuth;
CheckBox Remember;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        BottomNavigationView bandeauNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bandeau_navigation);
        bandeauNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.accueil);
        bandeauNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.accueil:
                    return true;
                case R.id.commerce:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),PageCommercial.class));
                    overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                    return true;
                case R.id.services:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Support.class));
                    overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                    return true;
                case R.id.info:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Info.class));
                    overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                    return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });


    mEmail = findViewById(R.id.email);
        mPassword = findViewById(R.id.password1);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mLoginBtn = findViewById(R.id.loginBtn1);
        mCreateBtn = findViewById(R.id.createText1);
        forgotTextLink = findViewById(R.id.forgotPassword);
        Remember=findViewById(R.id.remember_me);
        ////////////////////////////////////
        Remember.isChecked();
        sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("LoginPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
        /////////////////To get Stored Data/////////////////////////////////

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        String email=sharedPreferences.getString("email","");
        String passwords=sharedPreferences.getString("mot de passe","");

        mEmail.setText(email);
        mPassword.setText(passwords);
        mLoginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String email = mEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = mPassword.getText().toString().trim();



                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
                    mEmail.setError("Email manquant.");
                    return;
                }

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
                    mPassword.setError("Mot de passe manquant.");
                    return;
                }

                if(password.length() < 8){
                    mPassword.setError("Le mot de passe doit contenir au moins 8 caractères");
                    return;
                }
                if(Remember.isChecked()){
                    editor.putString("email",mEmail.getText().toString());
                    editor.putString("passowrd",mPassword.getText().toString());
                    editor.commit();
                }else {
                    editor.putString("email", "");
                    editor.putString("passowrd", "");
                    editor.commit();
                }
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                // authenticate the user

                fAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,PageTechnique.class));
                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Erreur ! " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }

                    }
                });

            }
        });

        mCreateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,Register.class));
            }
        });


        forgotTextLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final EditText resetMail = new EditText(v.getContext());
                final AlertDialog.Builder passwordResetDialog= new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
                passwordResetDialog.setTitle("Réinitialiser votre mot de passe ?");
                passwordResetDialog.setMessage("Entrer votre Email pour recevoir un lien de réinitialisation");
                passwordResetDialog.setView(resetMail);

                passwordResetDialog.setPositiveButton("Oui", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // extract the email and send reset link
                        String mail = resetMail.getText().toString();
                        fAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(mail).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Un lien de réinitialisation vous a été envoyé", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Erreur ! le lien de réinitialisation n'a pas été envoyé" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });

                    }
                });

                passwordResetDialog.setNegativeButton("Non", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // close the dialog
                    }
                });

                passwordResetDialog.create().show();

            }
        });


    }
}
```

**activity_login.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bandeau_navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:itemBackground="@color/noir"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selector"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/selector"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation" />

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bandeau_navigation"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:background="@drawable/saaalogo" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:background="@color/noir"
                android:ems="10"
                android:fontFamily="@font/futura_medium"
                android:hint="Email"
                android:padding="13dp"
                android:textColor="@color/blanc"
                android:textColorHint="@color/blanc"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:background="@color/noir"
                android:ems="10"
                android:fontFamily="@font/futura_medium"
                android:hint="Mot de passe"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:padding="13dp"
                android:textColor="@color/blanc"
                android:textColorHint="@color/blanc"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/remember_me"
                android:layout_width="377dp"
                android:layout_height="34dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:text="Se Souvenir de moi" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/loginBtn1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:background="@color/argent"
                android:fontFamily="@font/futura_medium"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:text="Se Connecter"
                android:textSize="18sp" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/createText1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"

                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/futura_medium"
                android:padding="13dp"
                android:text="Non inscrit ? Céer un compte"
                android:textColor="@color/noir"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/forgotPassword"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/futura_medium"
                android:text="Mot de passe oublié ?"
                android:textColor="@color/noir"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:visibility="visible" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this solution?

```
    /////////////////To get Stored Data/////////////////////////////////

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    **boolean isRemember=sharedPreferences.getBoolean("remember_me",false);**

    **if(isRemember){**
    String email=sharedPreferences.getString("email","");
    String passwords=sharedPreferences.getString("mot de passe","");

    mEmail.setText(email);
    mPassword.setText(passwords);
    **Remember.setChecked(true);**
    **}**
    mLoginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    ......
    
     if(Remember.isChecked()){
                **editor.putBoolean("remember_me",true);**
                editor.putString("email",mEmail.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("passowrd",mPassword.getText().toString());
                editor.commit();
     }else {
```

Comment: the problem of checkbox is resolved but only the email is stored and not the password how can I fix it?